# process.env.PORT prints weird string

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, port, console.log

When running `console.log("Express server listening on port " + port);` in node.js on a deployed Azure website, I get the following string

```
Express server listening on port \\.\pipe\d9797e42-9e1f-421c-91b9-3d86496eaeb8
```

What is this and how can I determine what port my site is really running on?

Comment: if you're running this on azure then this is likely running within iis-node and as such iis is the process that's bound to ports 80 and 443. iis then sends data to the node process via a named pipe, as you see here. edit: actually, that's not quite true, if this is on an azure website then it's your external load balancer that listens on 80 and 443, iis could be bound to any port. at the end of the day users access your site on ports 80 and 443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be running in port 80.

Seems like an internal instruction from the server

Comment: It was running on port 80. Thanks