# Node.js and MS Azure on process.env.port variable

Tags: node.js, azure

consider the following Node.js code:

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.port || 1337;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port);
```

It does not work in Microsoft Azure, because of string value in process.env.port variable (for example: \.\pipe\e289ed7e-b57b-46bb-8bba-ad8cd1f1529cf). Why is it happening?

Comment: There is some link about it! http://tostring.it/2014/07/09/nodejs-azure-and-iis/ but still the solution does not work!

Comment: Try:

process.env.PORT || process.env.PORT || 1337

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only thing should be done is to have a proper web.config file, for handling the named pipe port in Microsoft Azure. The simplest content for this file can be:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
      </handlers>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="DynamicContent">
            <match url="/*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

if your initial NodeJS file is **app.js**, replace the **server.js** strings in above content with it!

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It worked well on our app. Took us a day to work out this issue on Azure site.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It's amazing, in the top 2 google results for node js apps on Azure, this wasn't clear (or missing completely).  Also, there appears to be come inconsistency on the case of the 'port' (vs PORT) property on the `env` object.

Answer (score 2):

Should be case sensitive. Try:

```
process.env.PORT
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading the question, but it states that `process.env` is undefined, not just `process.env.port`.

Comment: I edited the question, there is some link about it!

http://tostring.it/2014/07/09/nodejs-azure-and-iis/

but still the solution does not work!

Comment: I don't have the tools atm but from my projects i can tell i've always used this variable and they also use it on their tutorials. You also use process.env to access app settings and connection string. It has to work. Maybe something else is causing the issue. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/

Comment: the same problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514750/process-env-port-prints-weird-string

Comment: A useful page: http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-nodejs-applications-in-iis-on.html